# Selenium Chromedriver server times out despite being available

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Java Selenium project that will not run on my machine, but does run on coworkers' machines with the same OS version (OSX 10.13.1), Chrome browser version (63.0.3239.84), and chromedriver version (2.34).  I get the message:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e) on port 18633
Only local connections are allowed.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1cc9:e0ab:f4e5:dd34%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
...
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:18633/status] to be available after 20005 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 29 more
```

however when I open http://localhost:18633/status in my browser I get a valid response:

```
{"sessionId":"","status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"alpha"},"os":{"arch":"x86_64","name":"Mac OS X","version":"10.13.1"}}}
```

I've tried swapping out chromedriver binaries, but I'm not really sure what else to do.  I get similar issues with geckodriver, but that may or may not be the same issue.
I have also tried creating a new user on my system and running it from that account, to account for user settings - No luck.

What am I missing here?  What info would be helpful to debug this problem?

Comment: same versions of Chrome browser?

Comment: Yes, same version of Chrome.  They get an "IllegalMonitorStateException" but it launches the chrome browser.  My instance doesn't even do that

Comment: did you give execute permissions to chromedriver?

Comment: Yes, it has execute permission and if I run it directly I get the output 'Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.'

Comment: i think the issue is that you have localhost resolving to an IPv6 address.

Comment: I disabled ipv6 for wifi, and I still have the issue - output now includes System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '10.10.8.24', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.2', java.version: '1.8.0_20'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161315/discussion-between-clay-h-and-corey-goldberg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
```

Clearly indicates the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance didn't get initiated. Hence *Driver info* is left **blank** as :

```
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Which inturn produces the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException
```

and

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

---

It would be tough to guess the actual reason without any visibility of your code block but in general we can solve this by downloading the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) binary from this [repository](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and passing the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* while initializing the *WebDriver* instance as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

---

### Key Points :

- Always use the **latest** version of the *Selenium Client* and *ChromeDriver* binaries.
- Always keep the *automatic updates* for the browser **enabled**.
- Always keep the **JDK** version updated (the current version being *JDK 8u241*)

Comment: I apologize, I apparently focused on the error I was getting and didn't see / omitted the initialization log.  I've included it in the output now - it's clearly starting the driver (I can even connect to the endpoint) but for some reason selenium is unable to communicate with the chromedriver server

Comment: The first 2 lines - Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e) on port 18633
Only local connections are allowed.

Comment: But you still face a `WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.` makes no difference to the apperant solution. Did you try out my Solution once?

Comment: I did try setting the system property, and got the same result.  However, updating my JDK version seems to have fixed it, so I'll be marking this as the answer.  Thanks for the suggestion!