# What is the difference between ChromeDriver and WebDriver in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-w3c-spec

If we create :

```
ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

chrome driver methods will be  executed.

And if we create :

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

again `ChromeDriver` methods are executed [as per method overriding].

Then why we write latter one only while executing?